# ASP.net MVC Core 2 Entity Framework returns null

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core-2.0

I´m creating an ASP.net Core 2 Application. There is an existing MS-SQL Database which I want to use in the Project.

I have added the Database with the following command:

> dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold
>   "Server=XXXX;Database=XXXX;Trusted_Connection=True;IntegratedSecurity=False;User
>   Id=XXXX;Password=XXXX" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
>   --output-dir Models/DB

In the Database there is the following Connection:

Persons ----- PersonsGroupRelationships ----- Groups

In the Entity Framework something like

```
db.Persons.First().Groups
```

should work. (In other MVC 5 Application it´s working perfect) But only the Persons attributes are loading correctly. The connection contains always null.

Even though the Person I have selected in the Entity Framework has Group Relationships in the code I get a null value returned.

[image: Failure Result]

As you can see the normal attributes that I have covered are working correct but there is a problem with every Relationship in the Database.

In the Model the Connection is implemented:

Persons.cs contains:

```
public Persons()
        {
            Groups = new HashSet<Groups>();
            PersonsCompaniesRelationships = new HashSet<PersonsCompaniesRelationships>();
            PersonsGroupsRelationships = new HashSet<PersonsGroupsRelationships>();
            SrmStudenten = new HashSet<SrmStudenten>();
        }

        ...OtherStuff...

        public Groups ResponsibilityGroupNavigation { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Groups> Groups { get; set; }
        public ICollection<PersonsCompaniesRelationships> PersonsCompaniesRelationships { get; set; }
        public ICollection<PersonsGroupsRelationships> PersonsGroupsRelationships { get; set; }
        public ICollection<SrmStudenten> SrmStudenten { get; set; }
```

The DB-Context file contains:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Persons>(entity =>
            {
                ...OtherStuff...

                entity.HasOne(d => d.ResponsibilityGroupNavigation)
                    .WithMany(p => p.Persons)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.ResponsibilityGroup)
                    .HasConstraintName("FK_Persons_Groups");
            });
```

I hope anyone of you can help me :-)

---

Update:

I have changed the Code like the Microsoft Doc is telling me for Lazy Loading

In the Context File i have added:

```
optionsBuilder
    .UseLazyLoadingProxies()
```

In the classes i changed it to virtual:

```
    public virtual ICollection<Groups> Groups { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PersonsCompaniesRelationships> PersonsCompaniesRelationships { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PersonsGroupsRelationships> PersonsGroupsRelationships { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SrmStudenten> SrmStudenten { get; set; }
```

Unfortunately the result still looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Are you using lazy loading and virtual properties? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#lazy-loading

Comment: `public ICollection<Groups> Groups { get; set; }` doesn't _look_ `virtual`.

Comment: In the "DB-Context"-file the attributes are virtual not in the Class Files. Even though, i tested adding virtual in the class files changed nothing :-(

Comment: You are definitely calling `UseLazyLoadingProxies`?

Comment: I have added ".UseLazyLoadingProxies()" in the Context file now and changed all attributes of all classes to virtual. Exception now says '((Castle.Proxies.PersonsProxy)temp).Groups' threw an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'

Comment: @DarkWing89: No lazy loading by default in EF core.

Comment: Did you read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#lazy-loading and add the `ILazyLoader lazyLoader` constructor parameters?

Comment: @DarkWing89: Lazy loading is pretty useless in MVC as the data has to move from a server side context to a client side context. Therefore, you need Eager Loading here more than Lazy loading.

Comment: I have added an update to my post above: I read the Microsoft Doc and added the changes - but no success :-(

Comment: Did you add the `lazyLoader` constructor parameters?

Comment: Lazy loading in EF-core 2.1 is still in the preview stage. Don't expect it to be working anywhere near flawlessly. And, as said, in a disconnected scenario, eager loading is more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following

```
IQueryable<Person> query = dbContext.Set<Person>().Include(x=> x.Groups);
var firstItem = query.FirstOrDefault().Groups;
```

You can alternatively do:

```
Person query = dbContext.Set<Person>().FirstOrDefault();
DbContext.Entry<Person>(query).Collection(x=> x.Groups).Load();
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced this kind of issue and i got a way steps:

Step 01: add packages for

```
 <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="EntityFramework" Version="6.2.0" />

     <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.1.2" />
     <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design" Version="1.1.6" />
     <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.1.0">
     <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
     <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers</IncludeAssets>
     </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Adjust supported .net version with compatible these referece.
Or you can find your desired references from nuget

add referece using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore; do not using system.data.entity; 
remove using system.data.entity; reference for .Include

Let's try. It's saved my time.
Thanks